java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error when calling Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(n) from console app or unit test in Android project
I'm getting the above-mentioned error when running either a "console" app (I mean main function without any GUI) or when running JUnit unit tests in Android Studio.
Full trace is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher.limitedParallelism$default(kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher, int, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.Object)'

    at com.example.coroutinesdeepdive.effective.safe.CompanyDetailsRepository.<init>(DispatcherMutableMap.kt:12)
    at com.example.coroutinesdeepdive.effective.safe.CompanyDetailsRepositoryTest$detailsFor should cache details$1.invokeSuspend(CompanyDetailsRepositoryTests.kt:116)
    at com.example.coroutinesdeepdive.effective.safe.CompanyDetailsRepositoryTest$detailsFor should cache details$1.invoke(CompanyDetailsRepositoryTests.kt)
    at com.example.coroutinesdeepdive.effective.safe.CompanyDetailsRepositoryTest$detailsFor should cache details$1.invoke(CompanyDetailsRepositoryTests.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:318)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher.processEvent$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestDispatcher.kt:24)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler.tryRunNextTaskUnless$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestCoroutineScheduler.kt:99)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$workRunner$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:327)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:10)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:310)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:168)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:160)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.coroutinesdeepdive.effective.safe.CompanyDetailsRepositoryTest.detailsFor should cache details(CompanyDetailsRepositoryTests.kt:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

Code where the error happens:
class CompanyDetailsRepository(
    private val client: CompanyDetailsClient,
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {
    private val details = mutableMapOf<Company, CompanyDetails>()
    private val dispatcher = dispatcher.limitedParallelism(1) // exception happens here
    ....
}

I know it's best practice to inject your scope and not rely on fixed dispatchers in unit tests, but this is 1) Just a testing/learning non-production env and 2) Why in a regular console app?
Thanks!
